# Fastest way to select a Single Document From Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there any preferred (fastest) way to select a SINGLE document from Azure Search  Or does one have to issue a query using its ID etc.
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/lookup-document

If you're using the.NET SDK: `searchIndexClient.Documents.Get("Put your document ID here")`